# Deleting all structure entries in C Programming

Tags: c, function, structure

I am having trouble deleting all entries into a defined structure. Here is the function code for a single entry deletion and my attempt at a "delete all" function

```
typedef struct person               //Structure Set up
{
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    char number[20];
} person;

void delInfo(int num_entries,person*contacts)
{
    char delfirst[20];      //Setting up Arrays to match entry
    char dellast[20];
    printf("\n First Name: ");
    scanf("%s",delfirst);
    printf(" Last Name: ");
    scanf("%s",dellast);
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<num_entries; i++)       //Going through contacts
    {
        if (strcmp(delfirst,contacts[i].fname)==0 && strcmp(dellast,contacts[i].lname)==0)      //Testing for match between entry and contacts
        {
            for (i=i; i<num_entries-1; i++)         //Shifting every contact AFTER match down one
            {
                contacts[i]=contacts[i+1];
            }
            if(num_entries !=0)
                contacts=(person*)realloc(contacts,sizeof(person)*(num_entries-1)); //Freeing memory at end by way of realloc
            printf("\n %s %s deleted from contacts\n\n",delfirst,dellast);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i == num_entries)
    {
        printf("\n Entry Not Found\n");
    }
    system("pause");
}

void deleteall(int num_entries,person*contacts)         //deleting all function
{
int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<num_entries;i++){
        contacts[i].fname=NULL;
    contacts[i].lname=NULL;
        contacts[i].number=NULL;
    }
free(contacts);

    printf("\n All contacts deleted\n\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

The problem is that they are incompatible types (trying to assign to array from void). Can I just use some kind of loop and use `realloc` to shorten the array to 0? I'm not sure how to just clear all entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The members of `struct person` are fixed in size, and are not allocated separately from the `struct` instance - short answer is that you cannot resize the arrays, nor can you deallocate their storage without deallocating the entire `struct` instance.  The absolute best you can do in this case is to write an empty string to each member to indicate it's not in use:

```
strcpy( contacts[i].fname, "" );
```

This does not change the size of the array, though.

In order to make the members of `struct person` resizable and/or deletable, you have to allocate them separately from the `struct` instance itself.  To do that, you need to declare them as *pointers* to `char`, as opposed to arrays of `char`:

```
struct person
{
  char *fname;
  char *lname;
  char *number;
};
```

When you create a new instance of `struct person`, you will need to allocate the memory for each member separately:

```
#define SIZE 20  // for this example, both number of contacts and size
                 // of each struct member

struct person contacts[size];
for ( size_t i = 0; i < j; i++ )
{
  contacts[i].fname = malloc( sizeof *contacts[i].fname * SIZE );
  contacts[i].lname = malloc( sizeof *contacts[i].lname * SIZE );
  contacts[i].number= malloc( sizeof *contacts[i].number * SIZE );
}
```

To resize any of the members, use `realloc`:

```
 char *tmp = realloc( contacts[i].fname, sizeof *contacts[i].fname * SIZE * 2 );
 if ( tmp ) contacts[i].fname = tmp;
```

Since `realloc` can potentially return `NULL`, it's recommended that you save the result to a temporary pointer variable, rather than immediately re-assigning it back to your original pointer; otherwise you risk losing track of the previously-allocated memory, leading to a memory leak.

You are also going to want to track how much memory is allocated for each member so you guard against buffer overruns.

To delete any of the members, use `free`:

```
free( contacts[i].fname );
```

Note that if you dynamically allocate an instance of `struct person`, you still need to dynamically allocate each member:

```
struct person *p = malloc( sizeof *p );
p->fname = malloc( sizeof *p->fname * SIZE );
...
```

This also means that you must deallocate each member *before* you deallocate the struct instance itself:

```
free( p->fname );
free( p->lname );
free( p->number );
free( p );
```

Simply freeing `p` will not free the memory allocated to `p->fname`, `p->lname`, and `p->number`.

Comment: Can you elaborate why I have to use a pointer to `char` instead of an array of `char` to deallocate/delete?

Comment: @NLhere: because we are dynamically allocating memory with `malloc`, which always returns a pointer value.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to delete the three fields of the structure as they are all statically allocated to 20 bytes each. You only need to free the memory within the three fields if they are dynamically allocated with malloc.

You do have to free all the dynamically allocated contacts though.

```
void deleteall(int num_entries,person*contacts)         //deleting all function
{
    for(int i=0;i<num_entries;i++){
        free(contacts++)
    }

    printf("\n All contacts deleted\n\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: this produces [Error] incompatible type for argument 1 of 'free' and [Note] expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'person'

Comment: when I try run that function it now "stops working" and returns a large number

Comment: You need to provide more information then. Is there a segmentation fault? How are contacts allocated prior to calling this function? Are they  in consecutive memory or spuratic?

Comment: @SimonBlack  you cannot free() individual elements of the contacts array because the whole array was likely allocated by malloc or calloc. It is not an array of pointers.

Comment: @SimonBlack person* contacts;    
    int num_entries=0;
    contacts = NULL;

Comment: @SimonBlack I do not know how to analyze the fault, but I am using `contacts = realloc(contacts, sizeof(*contacts) * num_entries);` to add contacts

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign NULL to contacts[i].fname or contacts[i].lname because these are arrays and NULL is a pointer value. Either use something like memset() or just do not do anything with the struct before freeing.